# I need help developing a commentbox

Tags: php, comments

Hi I recently discovered how to make a comment box in php! however when ever someone submits a comment it appears under the previous comment, i want the new comment to appear on top of the previous comment, also can you please tell me how i can make the comment box smaller ?

Thank you very much I hope you can help :)

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com","a5868186_test","honda33");
 mysql_select_db("a5868186_test");
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $comment=$_POST['comment'];
  $submit=$_POST['submit'];

 $dbLink = mysql_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com", "a5868186_test", "honda33");
   mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
  mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

if($submit)
 {
if($name&&$comment)
 {
 $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO commenttable (name,comment) VALUES 
 ('$name','$comment') ");
 }
 else
 {
  echo "please fill out all fields";
   }
   }
  ?>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Comment box</title>
  </head>

  <body>
   <center>
   <form action="commentindex.php" method="POST">
  <table>
   <tr><td>Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2">Comment: </td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="5"><textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>   
   </td></tr>
     <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment"></td></tr>
       </table>
      </form>
    <?php
       $dbLink = mysql_connect("mysql10.000webhost.com", "a5868186_test", "honda33");
      mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
     mb_language('uni');
      mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

     $getquery=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM commenttable ORDER BY id DESC");
      while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
      {
    $id=$rows['id'];
   $name=$rows['name'];
    $comment=$rows['comment'];
     echo $name . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . $comment . '<br/>' . '<br/>' . '<hr size="1"/>'
   ;}
   ?>

   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Apparently you need to reverse the sort order. The size of the comment box has nothing to do with the code you've shown here; use CSS.

Comment: Probably shouldn't post your db name/passwork out like this.  Also, look into mysqli so people don't inject into your database (it would be fairly easy to get into your database now)

Comment: not all the code pasted for some reason ...

Comment: i fixed the coding now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a date field to the MySQL table and sort on the date field.

Comment: thank you :) can you just show me where i edit "sort by date" on de scripting above :)